# Apache Ignite on EKS Fargate mode

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-eks, ignite, aws-fargate

Has anyone tried deploying Apache Ignite on AWS EKS Fargate.
Please share some critical Pros and Cons compared to deployment to AWS EKS standard with EC2.

#apacheignite #EKSFargate

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really a question about Apache Ignite, but is a question about AWS technology. Both rely upon containers, ostensibly meaning the Apache Ignite workload operates the same once the topology is established and the load balancer enables inbound connections.

Apache Ignite provides a discovery SPI which leverages Kubernetes for nodes running in containers to find and connect to each other. I don't know, but doubt Fargate is compatible, and so you should expect to need a custom discovery SPI (if you need elastic scale) or limit your cluster size to something you can manage with TCP discovery SPI, static node list, and AWS Fargate task networking over AWSVPC.

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/task-networking-in-aws-fargate/

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/introducing-cloud-native-networking-for-ecs-containers/

[https://blog.iron.io/aws-fargate-vs-aks/#:~:text=There%20are%20two%20important%20differences,by%20Amazon%20ECS%20or%20EKS](https://blog.iron.io/aws-fargate-vs-aks/#:%7E:text=There%20are%20two%20important%20differences,by%20Amazon%20ECS%20or%20EKS).

For the most ease of deployment, [GridGain Nebula](https://www.gridgain.com/products/gridgain-nebula) hosted clusters run in AWS. This is probably the easiest way to run Ignite on AWS, especially if you need to avoid committing to EC2 footprint management.